# Proper interpretation of "a" vs "any" in analysis proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm working on the following proof:

"Suppose that ($s_n$) is an increasing sequence with a convergent subsequence. Prove that $(s_n)$ is a convergent sequence."

Does the phrase "a convergent subsequence" in this context mean that any arbitrary subsequence of $(s_n)$ converges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any sequence is a subsequence of itself, requiring that *any* subsequence converges is the same as requiring the sequence converges.

Thus the statement is that there is *a* convergent subsequence.

Choose a convergent subsequence $(s_{n_k})$. Since it is increasing, its (finite) limit $l$ is the same as $\sup_k s_{n_k}$. I claim that $(s_n)$ is upper bounded by $l$, which implies convergence, being the sequence increasing.

Suppose there exists $n$ with $s_n>l$. Then there is $k$ such that $n_k>n$, by definition of subsequence. Then
$$
s_{n_k}\ge s_n>l
$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means there is [at least] one convergent subsequence.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed then. Isn't one able to construct a convergent subsequence from a divergent, monotonic sequence?

Comment: @TaylorTam Of course not.

Comment: @egreg Are you able to elaborate further? For example, consider the sequence: $\{[0,1)\} \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, \infty\}$. Wouldn't $\{[0,1)\}$ be a convergent subsequence?

Comment: @TaylorTam I think you should check the definition of sequence: a sequence must be of the form $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$, indexed by the natural numbers. The set that you provided is not a sequence.